# select where sum of time column & integer column is less than current_time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

I have two columns duration(integer) and start_time(time).

I have to select where sum of start_time and duration is greater than `current_time`.

Something Like this -

`Availability.where("start_time + duration < current_time")`
How to do this? I am using Postgres in Ruby-on-Rails

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To add an `integer` to a `time`, you'd probably want to convert the `integer` to an `interval` by specifying the units and casting. If the `duration` is in minutes then:

```
start_time + (duration || ' minutes')::interval > current_time
```

if the `duration` is seconds then:

```
start_time + (duration || ' seconds')::interval > current_time
```

Note that `||` is the string concatenation operator in SQL.

You can put one of those into a `where` call:

```
Availability.where("start_time + (duration || ' seconds')::interval > current_time")
```

Keep in mind that `'23:00'::time + '2 hours'::interval` is `01:00:00` (i.e. `time`s wrap around at midnight) so you might need to include a date component depending on what the data looks like and what the specific need is.